# Partition does not show up after editing fstab

Tags: partitioning, mount, nautilus, fstab

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit and wanted to have auto-mount of partitions (NTFS) after boot up. I edited the `/etc/fstab` file and added the following line of code:

```
UUID=5CB5FBB62D2AA5D5 /partitions ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

After this addition the partition with that UUID does not show up in nautilus left side navigation bar, instead all its contents are found in `/partitions`. How can I make the partition show up in nautilus?

Comment: @Zanna, yes, I can go to nautilus. Before mounting the partition was visible in the left side bar of nautilus as a partition, after editing fstab it is not seen and I need it to show.

Comment: does changing the mountpoint in fstab to something conventional like /media/windows instead of /partitions help (do `mkdir /media/windows` too)

Comment: @Zanna, let me try that.

Comment: @Zanna, that works. Please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Great, it's done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mountpoints for other partitions should be in `/media`

Make a new mountpoint for your NTFS partition:

```
mkdir /media/windows
```

or if not `windows` then whatever you prefer to call it

Now edit your `fstab` to correspond to that mountpoint:

```
UUID=5CB5FBB62D2AA5D5 /media/windows ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

On reboot the partition will show up as a device in the left panel.

See [fstab help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for reference.

Comment: can i do the same for ext4?

Answer (score 0):

1. To create a mount point first, run "sudo mkdir /media/drive_name", in place of "drive_name", choose anything you like
2. Now in terminal run "sudo nano /etc/fstab"

---

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
#Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
#device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name   devices
#that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#/ was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=3aea4570-4011-4247-9636-68317385324d /               ext4      errors=remount-ro 0       1
#swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b8dbe189-e496-4241-9d78-082447c5f632 none            swap    sw                0       0
#media on /dev/sda7
UUID=03F2C97A5650DB67   /media/drive_name                 ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user 0       0
```

---

3. In the above fstab file, “#media on /dev/sda7” has been manually added including the UUID (to see a partitions UUID run "sudo blkid /dev/sda*, *=partition_number") and for specific partition types, do the following,  if your partition type is fat32 then replace ntfs with fat32 and it applies likewise for any other partition types. press cntl+x , on confirmation promt press y to save the edits, and then reboot and you will see your desired drive will be auto-mounted on the partition list, :)