# Why aren't my mounted internal partitions showing in the Sidebar

Tags: mount, nautilus, automount

I have several partitions on my internal HDD. When I open a Nautilus window (any folder), the mounted partitions are not showing in the window's sidebar. This happened after I installed Ubuntu 16.10. Before that I was using Elementary OS without Nautilus.

The same problem exists on my guest account.

If I enter in Terminal `sudo nautilus` then all the partitions do show up in the sidebar, although some show their UUID instead of Label.

While trying to resolve this, I've modified my /etc/fstab several times (both manually and through Disks app), but without success. Every time the result is be the same - no partitions in the Sidebar.

An additional question, not sure if it's related, if I open Disks app, edit any partition's Mount Options and set `Automatic Mount Options` to On, that partition does not automatically mount. This is not the case on my other computers. Could it be in any way related to my problem above?

As I said, I've modified my /etc/fstab a few times already, but here's how it currently looks like:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=28f8f040-66ac-4edd-9b3e-670425ce8b31 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=25c545a9-51e2-46d3-9cc2-fc3d72fc8035 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=4172ee4d-d887-464c-862d-04b2acc4b287 none            swap    sw              0       0

# AMPP
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/54905800-7fed-4426-9fdc-c9a5748cac58 /mnt/54905800-7fed-4426-9fdc-c9a5748cac58 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

# DATA
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/EAA9-7535 /mnt/EAA9-7535 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
# UUID=EAA9-7535    /media/tomica/DATA  vfat    defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.utf8 0   0

# ntfs-data
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/40C9576D12CF1939 /mnt/40C9576D12CF1939 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

# win7
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/E06491F96491D320 /mnt/E06491F96491D320 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=E06491F96491D320   /media/tomica/win7  ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.utf8 0   0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/54905800-7fed-4426-9fdc-c9a5748cac58 /mnt/54905800-7fed-4426-9fdc-c9a5748cac58 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/EAA9-7535 /mnt/EAA9-7535 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/40C9576D12CF1939 /mnt/40C9576D12CF1939 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

**Edit:** So muru suggested that my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798026/partition-does-not-show-up-after-editing-fstab). I've tried both answers from that question and neither worked unfortunately.

I've also tried Byte Commander's suggestion from his comment, i.e. commented out all partitions from /etc/fstab and restarted my computer (twice) and that didn't work either. Any new suggestions are much appreciated.

**Edit 2:** As advised by user.dz, I'm adding here outputs of the following commands:

- `udisksctl dump > udist.dump`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23607475/
- `ps aux | grep udisks`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23607475/

Comment: If a partition has a fixed mount point in /etc/fstab, it won't be shown in the Nautilus sidebar. Only removable devices and dynamically mounted partitions are shown there. As a workaround, you can just make a bookmark to the partition's mount point directory there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partition does not show up after editing fstab](http://askubuntu.com/questions/798026/partition-does-not-show-up-after-editing-fstab)

Comment: @ByteCommander but this is not the case on any of my 5 computers. Each of them have their local HDD partitions shown in the Sidebar. This makes me ask: what exactly does 'fixed mount point' mean? Can I make my partitions not have fixed mount points? Or should I ask this instead: How can I make my partitions be dynamically mounted, as you say?

Comment: @muru I've already found the thread you cited, and tried its solution, but that didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ The partitions show in Nautilus if they are not configured in `/etc/fstab`. Remove their entry there or comment it out and reboot, then the partitions should show up in Nautilus. You can't specify the mountpoint this way though, it will automatically mount it to `/media/USERNAME/PARTITIONLABEL` if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ByteCommander that didn't quite work, sorry. I've commented out all my internal partitions in /etc/fstab and restarted my computer twice, but they're still not showing in the side bar. Is there anything  else I could try to resolve this?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ Could you check if the related packages are all installed `apt policy libudisks2-0 udisks2 libfdisk1` you could also try reinstalling them `sudo apt install --reinstall libudisks2-0 udisks2 libfdisk1`. Also verify if udisksd is running ? `ps aux | grep udisks` You should find two processes `gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor` as same user & `udisksd` as root. (post the output). If it is running, post the result of `udisksctl dump > udist.dump` to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: user.dz thanks for your comment.All three libraries are installed, and I can see the two udisks processes. Here's my udisksctl dump: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23607475/ For what it's worth, last night I relised that my /media/tomica folder lacks ACL permissions for my user. I think I fixed that by following this thread: http://goo.gl/e7V5Gy Can this be of any importance? How can I check if I did it properly? Also, I should remind that the problrm only exists with internal hdd. All external media are visible, even though they are all mounted at /media/tomica/$LABEL

Comment: And here's the output of `ps aux | grep udisks`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23607502/

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ, the udisks output looks normal, it could be an issue at nautilus level, if possible to try  with other file browser to confirm, `sudo apt install thunar` . I have no idea about ACL capabilities, I will take me some time to read about it.

Comment: @user.dz you may be on to something here. I have Nemo installed and the problem doesn't exist there. Could I somehow, I don't know, reset my Nautilus configuration, or something?

Comment: Just out of curiosity , what does `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist` tell you ?

Comment: @Serg ugh! This is my office computer and I've been connecting to it through Teamviewer all day today, but now I can't connect any more. Maybe network went down. I'll get back to you as soon as I'm able to check, ok? Sorry for this and thanks!

Comment: @Serg my output is this: `@as []`

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ, you may reset nautilus settings using `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/nautilus/` , logout then login again. If the issue remained, try reinstall it, `sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus nautilus-data`

Answer (score -1):

How did you configure your folder permissions?
If you can show them when you are root, maybe those folders don't allow users to see them because of permissions.
Try this (as root) (you can change "tomica" to your desired user):

```
# chown -R tomica:tomica /media
# chmod -R 775
```

NOTE: Only devices mounted in `/media` will show up in your file explorer as normal user.

Comment: Davidriver could you please provide source(s) for your answer? Because honestly, what you're suggesting sounds like a wild guess and a really bad idea. 1) First command would cause security threat, as per here: https://goo.gl/0DHXBb ; 1a) If done while any devices are mounted, it's even worse, destroys file ownerships recurrently! 2) Second command, you're not saying from which location should I perform it, so potentially also destroying permissions. Any source before I try them?